# What are the requirements to be added to the Einstein_MC_Predictive_Scores data extension?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, einstein

Documentation states:

> Einstein requires historical contact or subscriber engagement data,
> including at least 1,000 events in the 90 days before activation. It can take up to 90 days to generate initial scores, but engagement scores are typically available 24–48 hours after implementation.

But it is not clear if this is only for activation or if it's the same ongoing. Also not clear what "1,000 events" refers to. If it's subscriber level or account level.

Ref: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_anb_activate_einstein_engagement_scoring.htm&type=5

Comment: 1000 events is 1000 data points, which includes sends clicks open this is not per subscriber but total